# Expo build fails because profile is not associated with distribution certificate

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I have an ios app that I transferred from my Apple developer account to my client’s account (of which I am a team member).
Using the client’s expo account I am trying to build the latest release of the app. Using “expo fetch:ios:certs”, I retrieved the .p8, .p12, .mobileprovision, and .key files along with the related passwords.

However, when running “expo build:ios --clear-credentials” and choosing to provide my own certificates, I ran into an issue where the .mobileprovision file was linked to the wrong developer account.

So I created a certificate and profile on the client’s Apple developer account and ensured that the provisioning profile had certificate attached. I then downloaded it and ran “expo build:ios --clear-credentials” again. I used the same .p8 and .p12 files that the app originally used but uploaded the new .mobileprovision file.

The build still fails with error: “validateProvisioningProfile: provisioning profile is not associated with uploaded distribution certificate”

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you need to sign the new build with a distribution certification associated with your client's account rather than yours.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks! That was it. I created a new distribution certificate (.p12 file) and a new .mobileprovision file associated with the dist_cert and gave them to expo during the build process.

Comment: Thank you for this question. My problem was that I accidentally used a Development provisioning profile instead of a Distribution one. Then the expo build logs complained and gave me this same error.